# Difference between bmp image_size vs size

Tags: c, image, size, structure, bmp

my question is probably easy to answer.
so if i read from bmp structure i can see in bmp.h file that there is two different size

***bmp.h header***

```
struct bmp_header{
    uint16_t type;              // "BM" (0x42, 0x4D)
    uint32_t size;              // file size
    uint16_t reserved1;         // not used (0)
    uint16_t reserved2;         // not used (0)
    uint32_t offset;            // offset to image data (54B)
    uint32_t dib_size;          // DIB header size (40B)
    uint32_t width;             // width in pixels
    uint32_t height;            // height in pixels
    uint16_t planes;            // 1
    uint16_t bpp;               // bits per pixel (1/4/8/24)
    uint32_t compression;       // compression type (0/1/2) 0
    uint32_t image_size;        // size of picture in bytes, 0
    uint32_t x_ppm;             // X Pixels per meter (0)
    uint32_t y_ppm;             // X Pixels per meter (0)
    uint32_t num_colors;        // number of colors (0)
    uint32_t important_colors;  // important colors (0)
} __attribute__((__packed__));
```

after i read them i can  see that sometimes the bmp file `image_size` is the same as the `size` of the bmp, but sometimes its 54 bytes more than the normal `image_size`? why is that

i understand that the offset of the image is 54, but when i need to calculate that number in size?

PS: i know that how to calculate the normal `image_size`

example: 
***First***:

```
File size =  3126 bytes
File image_size: 3072 bytes
File offset. = 54
File dib. = 40
```

***Second***

```
File size = 16182 bytes
File image size = 16128 bytes
File offset. = 54
File dib. = 40
```

Comment: Hmm ... Since bmp format has been an MS thing, the documentation has been a bit sparse. It may be that some `.bmp` files are generated incorrectly [or there is an allowance for this]. When you get a non-standard `image_size`, what are the _other_ field values (e.g. `size`, `dib_size`, `offset`)? Is there a pattern?

Comment: @CraigEstey updated with example

Comment: Thanks for adding the extra data. But, in _both_ cases: `(size - image_size) == 54 == offset`. So, is there another file? With a hex editor, it's sometimes possible to visually see where the image data actually starts (e.g. it's packed 3 byte pixels). Does the "visual" starting offset match `offset` or can you see some extra hex data sandwiched in between? And, if so, what does it look like (e.g. Is the file header just dup'ed)? That is, is there an extra "BM" signature? Or, some other ascii two byte signature?

Comment: omg i cant read numbers i changed them and i thought that in the second example the size and the image size is the same :D so the problem is solved :D thank youu man

Comment: No worries. Second pair of eyes and all that ... Media file formats are always "interesting" ... Try `.wav`, `.mp3`, `.avi`, and `.mp4` sometime and you'll long for the days of a simple `.bmp` ;-)